# Java ProgressBar add value when something is downloaded

Tags: java, swing, download, jprogressbar

I want to add **JProgressBar** that will fill up during the download process in my program which will download files.

Thr question is How do I make that the progress bar will add the correct amount in the `setValue` 
(eg: when it downloads the last file, the JPB will be completed).

Note that the number of files to download are variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call:

```
progressBar.setMaximum(numberOfFilesToDownload);
```